# Why isn't my variable updating when I update a file?

Tags: python, json

My script works with a JSON database of student data and I'm having trouble updating the JSON and then immediately reading the updated information from the JSON. Every time I try to do this, I successfully edit the file, and update the variable associated with data on the file but the variable doesn't seem to update. The code is pretty dense so here is an outline of what I'm doing.

```
def refresh_db():
    global db
    with open('database.json', 'r') as database:
        db = json.load(database)

if requirement_is_met:
     pprint(db)
     EDIT_DB(changes)
     # DB is edited successfully
     refresh_db()
     pprint(db)
```

And the two versions of the database printed are exactly the same. I thought maybe this was a matter of needing to give python time to updated the database before reading it again, though even that seems dubious. I tried putting it a sleep() command to no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is most likely in `EDIT_DB()`, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Have you verified that `EDIT_DB()` successfully writes the file? Try opening the file in a text editor after calling `EDIT_DB()`.

Comment: I'd double check that there isn't a duplicate database.json lying around. That'd explain it... Maybe try the full path of the file when reading to be absolutely sure

Comment: @MuhammadAli As long as `refresh_db()` and `EDIT_DB()` are using the same filename, the existence of other files with the same name shouldn't matter.

Comment: Code we can't run ourselves to see the problem on our own machine doesn't count as a [mre]. Pseudocode can't be tested; if we can't test our fixes, anything we do is speculation, and Stack Overflow isn't the place for questions that can only be answered speculatively.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this to see if the file is updated

```
def refresh_db():
    with open('database.json', 'r') as database:
        db = json.load(database)
    return db

if requirement_is_met:
     pprint(db)
     EDIT_DB(changes)
     # DB is edited successfully
     db2 = refresh_db()
     pprint(db2)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem helpful, since `EDIT_DB()` apparently edits the global `db` variable.